# How can I hide controls in a youtube video when a user checked a input?

Tags: jquery, youtube, show-hide

I would like to create a "movie mode" for users can watch video without controls or video title.
My idea was is something like this:

```
<iframe src="//youtube.com/embed/8QgNZcAA9Pk" allowfullscreen="" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;" height="569" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<input type="checkbox" id="hide-controlls"> Hide controlls, like in a movie!
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>   
 $('#hide-controlls').click(function () {
        $(".html5-video-controls").toggle(this.checked);
    }); 
</script>
```

But looks like it dosen't work, and I don't know why, becouse the code seems to be correct, but the check box dosen't do anything.
What do I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

- controls=0 – Player controls do not display in the player. For IFrame embeds, the Flash player loads immediately.
- controls=1 (default) – Player controls display in the player. For IFrame embeds, the controls display immediately and the Flash player also loads immediately.
- controls=2 – Player controls display in the player. For IFrame embeds, the controls display and the Flash player loads after the user initiates the video playback.

Comment: Can you create a demo with checkbox?